# Draw text in circle with Java AWT (with the letters oriented accordingly)

Tags: java, text, geometry, awt, affinetransform

I'm trying to use Java AWT with `AffineTranform` to draw a given String in a circle, where the letters would also go upside down along the circle.

I started with the code from [the following program](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Drawtextalongacurve.htm) to draw text alone a curve.
I've also used the calculation of the coordinates from [a snippet I found here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/432101/how-to-make-it-like-the-numbers-in-a-clock) for drawing the numbers of an analog clock.

Below is my code. To be completely honest, I don't understand 100% how these methods work in order to fix my code. I've been fiddling around a bit in a trial-and-error attempt with the `coords` and `theta` values.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Main extends Panel {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Frame f = new Frame("Circle Text");
    f.add(new Main());
    f.setSize(750, 750);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  private int[] getPointXY(int dist, double rad){
    int[] coord = new int[2];
    coord[0] = (int) (dist * Math.cos(rad) + dist);
    coord[1] = (int) (-dist * Math.sin(rad) + dist);
    return coord;
  }

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    // Hard-coded for now, using 12 characters for 30 degrees angles (like  a clock)
    String text = "0123456789AB";

    Font font = new Font("Serif", 0, 25);
    FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
    g2.translate(200, 200); // Starting position of the text

    GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, text);
    int length = gv.getNumGlyphs(); // Same as text.length()
    final double toRad = Math.PI / 180;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
      //Point2D p = gv.getGlyphPosition(i);
      int[] coords = getPointXY(100, -360 / length * i * toRad + Math.PI / 2);
      double theta = 2 * Math.PI / (length + 1) * i;
      AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(coords[0], coords[1]);
      at.rotate(theta);
      Shape glyph = gv.getGlyphOutline(i);
      Shape transformedGlyph = at.createTransformedShape(glyph);
      g2.fill(transformedGlyph);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the current output:

[image]

I also noticed that if I use `(2 * length)` instead of `(length + 1)` in the `theta` formula, the first halve of the string seems to be in the correct positions, except not angled properly oriented (the character '6' is sideways / 90 degrees rotated, instead of upside down / 180 degrees rotated):

[image]

As I mentioned, I don't really know how the `AffineTransform` works regarding the given coordinates and theta. An explanation of that would be greatly appreciated, and even more so if someone could help me fix the code.
Also note that I want to implement this formula for a variable length of the String. I've now hard-coded it to `"0123456789AB"` (12 characters, so it's similar to a clock with 30 degrees steps), but it should also work with let's say a String of 8 characters or 66 characters.

---

EDIT: After the suggestions of *@MBo* I made the following modifications to the code:

```
int r = 50;
int[] coords = getPointXY(r, -360 / length * i * toRad + Math.PI / 2);
gv.setGlyphPosition(i, new Point(coords[0], coords[1]));
final AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, 0);
at.rotate(-2 * Math.PI * i / length);
at.translate(r * Math.cos(Math.PI / 2 - 2 * Math.PI * i / length),
             r * Math.sin(Math.PI / 2 - 2 * Math.PI * i / length));
Shape glyph = gv.getGlyphOutline(i);
Shape transformedGlyph = at.createTransformedShape(glyph);
g2.fill(transformedGlyph);
```

[image]

I now do have a circle, so that's something, but unfortunately still with three issues:

- The starting position of the first character is at ~4 o'clock instead of top.
- The characters aren't correctly angled with their tops towards the center of the circle
- The string is drawn counterclockwise instead of clockwise

The last issue is easily fixed, by changing the `-2` to `2` in the rotate:

[image]

But the other two?

---

EDIT2: I misread a small section of *@MBo*'s answer regarding the initial glyph set. It's now working. Here the resulting code changes again in comparison to the Edit above:

```
gv.setGlyphPosition(i, new Point(-length / 2, -length / 2));
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(coords[0], coords[1]);
at.rotate(2 * Math.PI * i / length);
```

[image]

Although I still see some minor issues with larger input Strings, so will look into that.

---

EDIT3: It's been a while, but I just got back to this, and I spotted my mistake for the length 66 test case I tried pretty easily: `360` should be a `360d`, because the `360/length` would use integer-division otherwise if 360 isn't evenly divisible by the length.
I now have this, which works as intended for any length. Note that the center isn't completely correct, for which the answer provided by *@Mbo* can help. My only goal was to make the circle of text (of length 66). Where it is on the screen and how big wasn't really that important.

```
int[] coords = this.getPointXY(r, -360.0 / length * i * toRad + Math.PI / 2);
  gv.setGlyphPosition(i, new Point(0, 0));
  AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(coords[0], coords[1]);
  at.rotate(2 * Math.PI * i / length);
  at.translate(r * Math.cos(Math.PI / 2 - 2 * Math.PI * i / length),
      r * Math.sin(Math.PI / 2 - 2 * Math.PI * i / length));
  at.translate(-FONT_SIZE / 2, 0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial angle is `Pi/2` for position and `0` for glyph rotation.
To set rotation and position properly, I suggest:

- put glyph in the coordinate origin (0,0)
- rotate it by `-2*Math.PI * i / length`
- translate it by `r*cos(Math.PI/2 - 2*Math.PI * i / length)` and `r*sin(Math.PI/2 - 2*Math.PI * i / length)`
- translate it by circle center coordinates

Steps:

[image]

Note - rotate, then shift.

This approach perhaps give good but not perfect result. For better looking you can add the first step - translate glyph by half of it's size to provide rotation about it's center. So sequence:

- shift by -glyphpixelsize/2
- rotate
- shift into final position (relative to zero, then shift by circle center)

Comment: So I use `double theta = -360 / length * i * toRad + Math.PI / 2;` both for the `getPointXY(100, theta)` and `at.rotate(theta)` calls? In that case I get [this as result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL8KS.png). How do I calculate the glyph rotation with this theta? Also, does the `dist` value in the `getPointXY` coordinate make a difference of the calculations, or is it only to adjust the size?

Comment: Emm, my mistake. Pi/2 is needed only for position. Will elaborate.

Comment: I still don't really get it tbh. I do have a circle now, but still with a bunch of issues, like a different starting position and a counterclockwise rotation. I've made an edit to my post with how I interpret the top suggestion of your answer, by putting the glyph at `0,0`, rotate it first, and then translate it. EDIT: The counterclockwise is easily fixed by changing the `-2` to `2` in the rotate.

Comment: but you put glyph in `coords` then make zero shift, while it must be near 0,0 !

Comment: Ah, of course!.. Now I get a result that's almost correct indeed, so I'll just have to apply the second part of your answer to correct the slight shift. Thanks thus far. I'll get back to you either with an accepted mark or if I have any additional questions.

Comment: Hi again. I tried it with a larger string, but there still seems to be some issues. Most likely because I don't really understand how your steps translate to the actual Java methods, and what you mean by 'translate it by circle center coordinates' that you edit in later on.  [Here is what it looks like now (with `r=150`).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7emve.png) Also, by 'shift' in the bottom part of your answer you also mean the 'translate'-method? If not, how do I shift?

Comment: Last edit still shows wrong operation sequence. Yes, shift means translate. At first implement top part of the answer

Comment: setGlyphPosition with  text length is wrong. I meant pixel size of glyph

Comment: Hmm. Where do I get this pixel size of the glyph from? I don't see a `getPixelSize()` method from the `GlyphVector`. I assume this pixel size depends on the font size that's used? Is it the `-gx.getPixelBounds(frc, coords[0], coords[1]).getX() / 2` (and similar for `y`)? (Probably not, since the result is completely deformed in that case.) How do I calculate this glyph pixel size?

Comment: Both font size and getPixelBounds might be rather good approximation. But at the first stage just put char in 0,0. Look at the picture added in answer

Comment: But font size is just 24, so if I use `-12` (or `-fontSize / 2`), [the result is still roughly the same..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiFQB.png) (Also, the `getPixelBounds` are `width=590` and `height=35` apparently if I print them to STDOUT, so I don't think that's the pixel size.. As for the 'shift by circle center', do you mean the coordinate of the center of the circle? Or perhaps the center of the current letter?

Comment: And I indeed saw the added pictures. I now have`gv.setGlyphPosition(i, new Point(0, 0));` -> `AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(coords[0], coords[1]);` -> `at.rotate(2 * Math.PI * i / length);`  -> `at.translate(r * Math.cos(Math.PI / 2 - 2 * Math.PI * i / length), r * Math.sin(Math.PI / 2 - 2 * Math.PI * i / length));` -> `at.translate(FONT_SIZE / 2, FONT_SIZE / 2);`, which gave the result in the screenshot above. FWIW, even if it's hardcoded, I'm mainly trying to figure this out for a string of size 66 for a codegolf challenge..

Comment: I don't understand your sequence of transformations.

Comment: Well, tbh, me neither.. I barely use AWT and am not really experiences with it. I mainly found those two code snippets I linked at the top of my answer, and tried to modify that curve into a circle for a String of length 66. I understand your three picture-steps in general, and they make sense, but I have no idea how to translate those steps into Java AWT code.. :/

Comment: gv.setGlyphPosition(i, new Point(0, 0)); at = identity (don't know how it looks); at.rotate; at.translate(r*cos,r*sin);  at.translate(circle center); If looks normally with small shifting, add translate(FONT_SIZE / 2) before rotate

Comment: Just got some time for this again, and I spotted my mistake pretty easily. I use `360 / length` instead of `360d / length`, so with the String of length 66 that I used for testing it would integer-divide, causing all the errors I had.. Your solution works like a charm, so thanks again. I had already upvoted and accept it prior, but figured I'd let you know I've found the final issue in my code and everything works now.